# Python CSV File - Want to filter specific rows/columns

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to analyse this CSV file. It has a lot of different countries (as an example below).

```
country iso2    iso3    iso_numeric g_whoregion year    e_pop_num   e_inc_100k  e_inc_100k_lo
Afghanistan AF  AFG 4   EMR 2000    20093756    190 123
American Samoa  AS  ASM 16  WPR 2003    59117   5.8 5   6.7 3   3   4
Gambia  GM  GMB 270 AFR 2010    1692149 178 115 254 3000    1900    4300
```

I want to try and obtain only specific data, so only specific countries and only specific columns (like "e_pop_numb"). How would I go about doing that?

The only basic code I have is:

```
import csv
import itertools

f = csv.reader(open('TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv'))

for row in itertools.islice(f, 0, 10):
    print (row)
```

Which just lets me choose specific rows I want, but not necessarily the country I want to look at, or the specific columns I want.

IF you can help me or provide me a guide so I can do my own learning, I'd very much appreciate that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use pandas python library. Please follow the article as here below there is a snippet code to iluminate your thoughts.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("https://pythonhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Income_data.csv")
df2.loc["Alaska":"Arkansas","2005":"2007"]
```

source of this information: https://pythonhow.com/accessing-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells/

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will probably be the easiest way. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

To get it run

```
pip install pandas
```

Then read the csv into a dataframe and filter it

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(‘TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv’)
df = df[df[‘country’] == ‘Gambia’]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

with

```
open('file') as f:
  fields = f.readline().split("\t")
  print(fields)
```

If you supply more details about what you want to see, the answer would differ.